# 未ログイン状態でコメントしようとした時のポップアップでレイアウトが崩れている

Tags: バグ, 再現性なし, デザイン

ログインしていない状態でコメントを追加しようとするとログインを促すポップアップが表示されますが、一部分だけ余白が少なすぎるように感じます。細かい話ですが・・・。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

CSS http://cdn.sstatic.net/jameta/all.css?v=7520815915ac
サイトバージョン rev 2015.2.16.2302
Chrome 42.0.2305.2 / Windows 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

問題の報告から随分と時間が経っており、デザインも変わっているのでいったん [再現性なし](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e5%86%8d%e7%8f%be%e6%80%a7%e3%81%aa%e3%81%97) にしたいと思います。(翻訳は更新しないといけませんね)

**2020-08-20 時点で (未ログイン時に) コメントを追加しようとした時のポップアップ表示**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]